# Prove that $x^Ty$ is diagonalisable where $x,y$ are row vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Prove that for $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, $x^Ty$ is diagonalisable where $x,y$ are row vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the result is false.

For example, let $x=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}$ then $$x^Ty=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
That matrix has $0$ as only eigenvalue and it is clearly not diagonalisable.

Actually, the statement should be

> Let $x,y$ be two non zero row vectors, $x^Ty$ is diagonalisable iff the scalar product $\langle x,y\rangle \neq 0$.

Indeed, let $M$ be the matrix $M=x^Ty$ then $$\begin{equation} M^2=x^Tyx^Ty=x^T(yx^T)y=\langle x, y\rangle \cdot M \qquad (1)\end{equation}$$

- If $\langle x,y\rangle \neq 0$, the minimal polynomial of $M$ has simple root(s) hence $M$ is diagonalisable.
- Assume now that $M$ is diagonalisable and $\langle x,y\rangle =0$. From $(1)$ we get that $M^2=0$ and thus $M=x^Ty=0$ because $0$ is the only eigenvalue. Hence, either $x$ or $y$ has to be the null vector. A contradiction. Hence if $M$ is diagonalisable then $\langle x,y\rangle \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

That's wrong. For $x = (0,1)$ and $y = (1,0)$, 
$$ x^t y = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
$$
is not diagonizable.